# #If DEBUG is ignored (VB.net or C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have several of these in my code which have been working fine so far:

```
#If DEBUG Then    
   ... some code here       
#End If
```

Now, i am noticing that, lately, the code inside the " #If DEBUG Then ... #End If"
gets execute also in "Release Mode".

This is strange and did not happen before. What could have happened so that
the  #If DEBUG  are now being ignored (they are ignored both in debug in the IDE or the final executable) ?

I have applied Clean, Rebuild, etc.: no luck. Thank you for any hints and help.

-Pam

Comment: If you come to this post with new project format (netcore/standard), as I did, [it's a VS bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55030257/837726)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you understand the difference between how you're running the code and how you're building it. Too many people equate "launching in a debugger" with "the debug version" and "launching not in a debugger" with "the release version". They're completely orthogonal - you can launch a release build in a debugger (typically with less information available) and you can launch a debug build not in a debugger. Apologies if you were already aware of this.

Now, assuming you really *have* changed the project configuration you're building to Release, you need to check the project properties for that specific configuration. I don't know what it looks like in VB, but in C# in the project properties, in the build tab, there will be a list of defined symbols - *that* is what affects whether `#if DEBUG` code is built or not. Perhaps someone has copied over the project configuration from Debug into Release?

EDIT: One way to check this at *build* time is:

```
#if DEBUG
#error This shouldn't happen
#endif
```

In a release build, that *should* build without error. In debug, it won't.

EDIT: Another option is that your overall *solution* configuration is now referring to the wrong *project* configuration types. I can't remember the exact menu name, but if you look around Project for Configuration Manager, you should be able to bring up a grid mapping "Project" and "Solution Configuration" to the project configuration to build.

Comment: I havent touched the default configuration. Yes i am building it in release mode. Even in the final executable the #if debug are now ignored (this did no happen up to yesterday ??).

Comment: @Pam: See my edits for another diagnostic test and another area to check.

Comment: If i use the code above, it says (Release mode in IDE): Error 10 'If', 'ElseIf', 'Else', 'End If', 'Const', or 'Region' expected.

Comment: In VB you use `#If (expression) Then` `#End If` but unfortunately there's no `#error` [VB language reference on compiler directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx)

Answer (score 29):

C# Project ( Visual Studio )

1. go to: Project Properties -> Build(tab)
2. Select Configuration: **Release**
3. **Uncheck** "Define DEBUG constant"
4. Now select Configuration: **Debug**
5. **Check** "Define DEBUG constant"
6. In your code, you can now type the following ( DEBUG with uppercase )

> ```
> #IF DEBUG
>
> // Debugging code goes here
>
> #ENDIF
> ```

Answer (score 23):

> Under Project Properties / Compile / Advanced Compile Options there is
>   a checkbox called "Define Debug Constant" that sets this.

Check out: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_24658238.html

EDIT: Try this initializing with this:

```
#If CONFIG = "Debug" Then
#CONST DEBUG = true

#if CONFIG = "Release" Then
#CONST DEBUG = false
```

Comment: Linking to Experts Exchange in a Stack Overflow post?!

Comment: It is checked, as usual. I did not touch it.

Comment: @Pam: "It is checked, as usual"? It should NOT be checked in Release build.

Comment: Hmm. When I linked it I could just scroll to the bottom and it would show me all the other answers. and @BoltClock it was the first answer to appear in my search :P

Comment: Wait there!  In the Release mode the DEBUG must be unchecked ? And what about trace ? Must be checked or not ?

Answer (score 6):

Did you, by any chance, tick the "Define DEBUG constant" for the Release configuration, while you were in the Project Properties / Build?

Also make sure you are not building the project-level Debug configuration within the solution-level Release configuration (see the Configuration Manager).

Comment: No i did not. In the ADVANCED COMPILE OPTIONS define Debug is checked. Even in the finale EXE the #if debug is ignored!

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem where "DEBUG" was never true. Tried by doing an uncheck and check of the "Define DEBUG constant" checkbox and rebuilding everytime but that did not work.

My solution was to **define "DEBUG" manually in the "Conditional compilation symbols"** textbox for the Debug configuration. When rebuilding, **Visual Studio 2019 automatically removed the DEBUG symbol from the textbox** (because this indeed should not be there) and from then on **it worked again**. When i switched from Debug to Release the correct lines got greyed out.
This seems to be a possible bug in VS 2019 (16.4.5)?

Answer (score 1):

Also remember `#if DEBUG` must be in uppercase. e.g. `#if debug` won't work.

Comment: @user1306322 Both the answer and your comment are only valid in the case of C#.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I don't have any recent experience with VB, but do you know if capitalization of "#If", "#IF", "Debug" and "debug" matters in VB? From what I can tell, in c# "#if" must be lowercase and "DEBUG" must be all caps for it to work.

Comment: They don't matter. VB isn't case-sensitive like C#. Even `#iF dEbUg tHEN` would work just fine. However, the proper way to write it in VB would be `#If DEBUG Then` *which is what VS would do for you if you have the auto-formatting (pretty listing) enabled*. In short, it's `if`/`#if` in C# and it's `If`/`#If` in VB, however, *unlike C#,* the VB compiler will accept both.

Comment: I was using c# and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`undefine` **DEBUG** and that will not execute that portion.

Comment: what? I am not getting the hint

Comment: @Pam: You said that the code is executing even in release mode. That's because DEBUG is defined somewhere in your code. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET make sure about this line in Web.Config file:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
```

So if debug="true" your project runs in DEBUG mode.

Comment: This has nothing to do with conditional compilation.

Comment: Nothing to do with conditional compilation but runtime !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VB.NETFramework v4.5 then use like

```
If Debugger.IsAttached Then
    '... some code here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

On NET CORE C#, it's not exactly a "check". You will need go to "project properties > Compilation > General > Custom compilation symbols".
Once there, you can ADD the DEBUG var (or another of the supported on you Visual Studio enviroment).

Type the name and press Add.

[image: Project properties vars]