# Visual Studio ignores the code inside #if DEBUG / RELEASE scope and doesn't check for errors or autocompletes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, preprocessor-directive

I've been writing an `#if DEBUG`, `#else`, `#endif` fragment of code, and I noticed that Visual Studio doesn't let me use autocomplete to fulfill partially typed member names, and it doesn't check the greyed out inactive code for errors. The only way I've found to make it care again is to switch the build mode from Debug to Release. But that's inconvenient and feels like there's a better way.

example:

```
#if DEBUG
    throw;
#else
    throw new exc // I want to use autocomplete here but can't because it's greyed out
#endif
```

How do I make VS stop ignoring the other code inside the other configuration's scope of `#if DEBUG`?

Answer (score 9):

It is purpose of conditional compilation, it is working as intended. With conditional compilation application can ignore certain code at compilation. Your application in Visual Studio is running in Debug Mode so compiler is ignoring code inside `#else`part.

Run your application in **Release** mode then `#else` code will be available but  `#if DEBUG`will not be available.

[image]

**Update**

---

For checking both `#if DEBUG` & `#else` you need to run application twice.

1.Once in **debug** mode in which code with `#if DEBUG` like :

[image]
[image]

here application is in debug mode so `#if DEBUG` condition code is active..

2. Run application in **release** mode for checking code in `#else` condition. Here other part will be able to use autocomplete & debug too.

[image]
[image]

---

Refer microsoft docs for more info on this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/debug-compiler-option

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/listed-by-category

Comment: Ok so I guess I want to do it another way then if I want my code to be checked for errors and allow autocomplete. Your answer explains why it happens, but not how I can do what I explained.

Comment: You can check code for error but at one time only `#if` in debug mode & other code in `#else` in release mode. I am updating answer

Comment: Just an idea, remove `#if` & `#else` for checking code & getting autocomplete after code is tested & autocomplete is used for all code put  `#if` & `#else` again.

Comment: yea, that's basically what I did, but by commenting instead of deleting

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a late answer, but it still applies to this day.

TL;DR: `this is a VS bug`, which affects only affects netstandard/netcore projects (or simply put, the new .csproj format).

The workaround is... nasty! `Reload the project file` (or close and reopen VS).

The good news: this does not affect compilation :)

You can read more [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246684/intellisense-doesnt-work-for-if-debug-constant-whe.html) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2733).

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the file define both constant:

```
#define DEBUG
#define RELEASE
```

Next, use two `if` condition instead of `if/else`.

```
#if DEBUG
            // autocomplete works
#endif
#if RELEASE
            // autocomplete works
#endif
```

Of course, you must delete/comment out these defines before compiling the project.

In my opinion, this awkward and fraught with mistakes.

Comment: I really expected there to be a checkbox to force code processing within the inactive scope, but I suppose the intention of the entire thing contradicts my wish.