# Visual Studio 2013 DEBUG preprocessor directive always defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I added a new project to a Visual Studio 2013 (12.0.40629.00 Update 5) solution, and suddenly the `#if DEBUG` checks pass for compiled code, even in release. The 'define DEBUG constant' is disabled for the release build, and all projects are built as release (as seen in the configuration manager).

I find several things on Google that this is a known bug that can be worked around by unloading and reloading the project (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55030257/648159), but that doesn't help).

I also tried `undef DEBUG`, but also no luck.

Existing projects in the solution works, but this new one doesn't. It's a Dotnet standard 4.5, but setting it to 3.5 doesn't help.

As an indication of what happens in a release build:

[image: Screenshot if debugging disabled code]

Visual studio thinks it's inactive code, but it's obviously compiled in and executed (and debugged).

This makes it impossible to make release builds.

Edit: to elaborate on the question below: it's not a unit test, but I am starting to suspect that debug DLLs are taken. To be able to release, I quickly deleted all the code in `#if DEBUG`, and even after compiling that, the software tried to open the debug DB. When I recompiled debug, it was OK.

Comment: This is quite unlikely of course.  You must not assume that the debugger can place the highlight correctly in a Release build, the Debug configuration exists to help it not be confused.  Two options in Tools > Options > Debugging > General affect this, "Suppress JIT optimization" and "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".

Comment: The code is actually executed. I can step through the foreach loop, and it does what it normally does in debug, but then in the release build. The initial symptom of the release build was that it tried opening the debug DB, which is code that is normally not compiled in.

Comment: If this is a unit test then ensure that the unit test runner doesn't try to use the debug build.  Use Debug > Windows > Modules to verify that the DLL came from the location you expected.  Look at the file timestamps with Explorer to ensure that a Debug build does not overwrite the Release version.  Use ildasm.exe or your favorite decompiler to verify the code generation of the method.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited my question with a bit more info on that.

Comment: Well, that tells you that you are in fact loading the Debug build of the DLL.  No real idea why the Modules window wasn't helpful.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to get more insight in how that happened.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't see that 'Modules' window option. Actually, I just remembered, it also didn't help when I disabled the DEBUG constant in the Debug config, so it's not quite as plain as the wrong DLL. Unfortunately, I'm running out of time here, so to be continued.

Comment: I don't know if you already checked it. Right click on the Solution in the "Solution Explorer" -> "Properties" -> "Configuration Properties" -> "Configuration Manager". Perhaps the configuration got broken when you added the project and and there is a debug project config in the release solution config.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this again. I don't know how I did it, but apparently I added references as links to debug DLL's, instead of to projects in the solution.

This diff of a `csproj` explains it:

```
-    <Reference Include="Bla.Utils">
-      <HintPath>..\BlaUtillLib\obj\Debug\Bla.Utils.dll</HintPath>
-    </Reference>
     <Reference Include="System" />
     <Reference Include="System.Core" />
     <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
@@ -166,12 +163,19 @@
       <Project>{e2bec86c-1c02-4182-8117-740612ed9330}</Project>
       <Name>DbDAL</Name>
     </ProjectReference>
+    <ProjectReference Include="..\BlaUtillLib\Bla.Utils.csproj">
+      <Project>{6de20344-62f7-45f7-92cd-dbeb19cdc4c5}</Project>
+      <Name>Bla.Utils</Name>
+    </ProjectReference>
```

I don't know how this happens. I don't go out of my way to browse to DLL's of the solution's own projects.